# javascript /jQuery - For Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

I have a query ajax response which I then use to set the array variables.
Is there anyway to use a 'For Loop' to change to #name so that I don't have to write out a line of code to set each array element.

```
array[0]=$('#event00',response).html();
array[1]=$('#event01',response).html();
array[2]=$('#event02',response).html();
array[3]=$('#event03',response).html();
```

So '#event00' could be used in a for loop to change to '#event01' etc

Comment: drop the extra Zero '0'. It will help you a lot, trust.. and I'd leave out the 00 and 0 count all together.

Comment: What ended up working for you?

Answer (score 46):

Use a regular for loop and format the index to be used in the selector.

```
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var selector = '' + i;
    if (selector.length == 1)
        selector = '0' + selector;
    selector = '#event' + selector;
    array.push($(selector, response).html());
}
```

Comment: Completely agree Greg!! Native functions are always faster than any helper counterparts.

Answer (score 8):

What about something like this?

```
var arr = [];

$('[id^=event]', response).each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).html());
});
```

The `[attr^=selector]` selector matches elements on which the `attr` attribute starts with the given string, that way you don't care about the numbers after "event".

Answer (score 2):

`.each()` should work for you. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ or http://api.jquery.com/each/ or you could use `.map`.

```
var newArray = $(array).map(function(i) {
    return $('#event' + i, response).html();
});
```

Edit: I removed the adding of the prepended 0 since it is suggested to not use that.

If you must have it use

```
var newArray = $(array).map(function(i) {
    var number = '' + i;
    if (number.length == 1) {
        number = '0' + number;
    }   
    return $('#event' + number, response).html();
});
```

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL roger, i will add that.

Comment: How does this relate to the code in the question, which is _setting_ array values? Calling `.html()` on a line by itself doesn't do anything...

Comment: @nnnnnn good catch, I forgot to add it to the array. I have removed it and replaced it with map.